# My excel userform becomes unresponsive the next time I load it

Tags: excel, user-controls, userform, vba

I have two forms, a login form to authenticate users to enter the system and a main form to work with if the authentication is successful. I work with an access database to search for the valid users and also to populate lists in the main form.

[image: The user form for authentication]

And here is the code for that:

```
Private Sub CancelCommandButton_Click()
    CloseDatabase
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ConfirmCommandButton_Click()
    ...

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ConnectDatabase
End Sub

Private Sub OpenMainForm()
    Unload Me
    MainForm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And here is the code for managing main form load-up and close:

```
Public Sub UpdateControls()
    PopulateUserList
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    sTag = Split(Me.Tag, "|")

    If sTag(0) <> "1" Then
        Me.MainFormMultiPage.Pages(0).Enabled = False
        Me.MainFormMultiPage.Value = 1
    Else
        Me.MainFormMultiPage.Pages(0).Enabled = True
        Me.MainFormMultiPage.Value = 0
        UpdateControls
    End If

    UserLabel1.Caption = sTag(1)
    UserLabel2.Caption = sTag(1)
    UserLabel3.Caption = sTag(1)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        ' Tip: If you want to prevent closing UserForm by Close (×) button     in the right-top corner of the UserForm, just uncomment the following line:
        ' Cancel = True

        Dim answer As Integer
        answer = MsgBox("ÂíÇ ãØãÆäíÏ ˜å ãí ÎæÇåíÏ ÇÒ ÓÇãÇäå ÎÇÑÌ ÔæíÏ¿",     vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "ÎÑæÌ ÇÒ ÓÇãÇäå")

        If answer = vbYes Then
            CloseDatabase
        Else
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    loginForm.Show
End Sub
```

When I close the main form by clicking 'X' button, the login form reappears and the main form is closed; But when I login again (preferably using the same credentials) the main form is displayed but totally unresponsive (No list population, 'X' button doesn't work or any other controls in the form).

What should I do? Does the code in the UserForm_CloseQuery() unload the main form and all of its macros and I can't get the required events back to function or am I missing something?

It's not a time I started coding VBA and I can't make the head or tail of it easily when new problems arise. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your forms are modal, change the login form code to:

```
Private Sub OpenMainForm()
    Me.Hide
    MainForm.Show
    Me.Show
End Sub
```

and remove the `Userform_Terminate` code from the main form. That will mean that the login form automatically shows when the main form is closed.

Comment: Thank you so much Rory, Actually I got an error and a little change is required and I also changed login form initialize event to activate, now it works just fine.